# What is the file size limit in temporary directory in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions, unnotificationattachment, unnotificationserviceextension

I am trying to save an image of size 7.9MB downloaded from [here](https://images.pexels.com/photos/853199/pexels-photo-853199.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=4k-wallpaper-background-beautiful-853199.jpg&fm=jpg). But at line 'try data.write...' the extension crashes and I get this in console.

> kernel EXC_RESOURCE -> Notification Extension[3137] exceeded mem limit: ActiveHard 12 MB (fatal)
>
> kernel 46710.034 memorystatus: killing_specific_process pid 3137 [Notification Extension] (per-process-limit 3) - memorystatus_available_pages: 73906
>
> ReportCrash    starting prolongation transaction timer
>   default 18:39:53.104640 +0530
>
> ReportCrash    Process Notification Extension [3137] killed by jetsam reason per-process-limit

Is it because 7.9MB size is too much for it too handle. If it is then it doesn't make sense as it is necessary to save media in temporary storage before creating an UNNotificationAttachment object. In official documentation the limit for png files is given as 10 MB and for videos it is 50 MB. How do I solve this?

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let folderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString

guard let folderURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(folderName, isDirectory: true) else {
        return nil
}

do {
    try fileManager.createDirectory(at: folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    let fileURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent(fileIdentifier)
    try data.write(to: fileURL, options: [])
    let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: fileIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
        return attachment
} catch let error {

}
```

Comment: Looks like it is a memory issue not storage space issue.

Comment: Is your image compressed? It might get over 12MB if your data  is jpeg and gets uncompressed  to UIImage somewhere in the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked this way. Instead of downloading data using `NSData(contentsOf:)`, I used `URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with:)`. This stores the downloaded data by itself so no need for us to write it. It just has to be moved to desired temporary location using `FileManager.shared.moveItem(at:to:)`. Looks like the problem was with `NSData.write(to:options:)`function. It has some size limit on it.

```
URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (location, response, error) in

    if let location = location {
        let tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
        let tmpFile = "file://".appending(tmpDirectory).appending(url.lastPathComponent)
        let tmpUrl = URL(string: tmpFile)!
        try! FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: tmpUrl)
        if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "notification-img", url: tmpUrl) {
        bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
        }
    }
    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
}.resume()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there **is** a size limit on the contents you can write to the temporary directory (other than free space) but I can tell you that I've written client apps that write hundreds of megabytes to that directory. That's not your problem.

Comment: the limit is the current free space and if exceeded catch will throw an error

Comment: Do you keep tabs on the size of the `tmp` folder or do you just let the OS purge it when it grows too large?